# Change background colour in children of ExpandableList when scroll

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableList with 3 items, each item have different items with different properties, such as background color, image,...

I would like to change the colour of child item when I click it. I can change the colour when I don't scroll because I save a tag with the view. But the problem appear when I scroll and click other child. The last child selected don't change the colour background.

```
expandableList.setOnClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){
...
  View view =(View)parent.getTag();
  //Change last view colour
  view.setBackgroundResourece(R.drawable.background_noselect);
  ...
  parent.setTag(v);
}
```

In the adapter:

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  ...
  if(isSelect()){
      convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_select);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I can change the colour when I don't scroll because I save a tag with the view. But the problem appear when I scroll and click other child. " - What does this mean? Please can you explain

Comment: The goal is that I have a expandablelist and when I click an element, I change the colour of background (for example red), after, I click another element and I change the colour of background (for example red) and I change the colour of first element that I clicked (for example blue). I can do these things without scrolling the list but when I scroll the list I can change the colour of first element I clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by: "I can do these things without scrolling the list" Do you mean that you can do it without encapsulating the XML within a ScrollView? Or you can do it but when its in the process of scrolling it doesn't work? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I can't change the color of the view when I scroll the expandableList. I have done two things. The first is that I have added this code in the activity:

```
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            View view= null ;   
                //Select's item     
            select  = expandableListInfo[groupPosition].get(childPosition);
                            //Get the last element visible in expandableList
            int lastVis =expandableList.getLastVisiblePosition();
                            //Get the first element vsible in the expandableList
            int firstVis = listadoPedidos.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int count = firstVis;
            while (count <= lastVis) {
                int viewPosition=count-firstVis;
                long longposition = expandableList.getExpandableListPosition(count);
                int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(longposition);
                if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                   int groupPositionLast = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(longposition); 
                   //Get the object selected before
                   //This tag is save in the adapter               
                   Object lastObject = (Object)parent.getTag(R.id.tag_select);
                   view =(View) parent.getChildAt(viewPosition);
                   Object ob=view.getTag(R.id.tag_select);
                   if(ob.equals(lastObject)){
                       //Change colour view
                   }
                }
            count++;
            }
           ...
            parent.setTag(R.id.tag_select, select);

            return false;
        }

    });
```

The second thing is that in the adapter add in getChildView the next code:

```
convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_select, object);
if(parent.getTag(R.id.tag_select).equals.object){ 
 //// TODO 
}
```